# Add watermark to pdf using iText using ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: pdf, grails, groovy, itext, bytearrayoutputstream

The pdf is stored in a database as a byte[].  I want to add a watermark to the pdf and store the stamped file as a byte[], also in the database.  This is a Grails application, so the code is in Groovy. Here it is:

```
def stampDocument(byte[] orig) {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(orig)
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    //baos.write(orig, 0, orig.size())
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, baos)
    com.itextpdf.text.Image image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(new URL("http://localhost:8080/IDSG/assets/stamp.jpg"));
    image.setAbsolutePosition(65f, 10f);
    image.scalePercent(40f);
    int i = 1
    while(i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()){
        PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i)
        content.addImage(image)
        i++
    }
    return baos.toByteArray()
}
```

The problem is that the pdfStamper does not seem to take notice of the pdfReader.  Calling some methods (getFileLength() and getInfo()) on the pdfReader returns valid data, so the pdfReader seems to be OK.  Same with the image.

If the commented code (baos.write(orig, 0, orig.size()) is uncommented the original file is saved as the stamped file, but without the watermark. It's a bit bigger than the original, but renders perfectly.

With the code mentioned above commented out, like in the code example, the returned byte[] is much smaller than the original and not a valid pdf file.

This worked well with files on the disk. But I'm stumped here.  It seems only something small is needed.  Any help will be appreciated.  I've been battling with this for hours and searched the web.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting one important line:

```
pdfStamper.close()
```

Insert it right before this line:

```
return baos.toByteArray()
```

When you close the stamper, objects such as the root dictionary and the cross reference stream are written to the `OutputStream`. Without these objects, you don't have a complete PDF.

Comment: Bruno, Thanks for your answer.  Close does not only close the stamper, but writes everything to the baos.  Close threw this error:

Comment: Indeed: you want everything to be written to the `baos` (otherwise you have an incomplete PDF file). The error you are getting is related to the XMP data. Which version of iText are you using? I haven't seen this error in a very long while. Also: are you sure the XMP metadata in the original PDF is correct? It seems that Adobe's XMP parser can't parse it.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Sorry for tanking so long to get back.  It was 5.5.6 downloaded from the site.  I got it to work even with Groovy code, but using the Itext supplied in Grails, an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Close threw this error:

```
> Caused by AbstractMethodError:
> javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
> ->>  423 | createDocumentBuilderFactory in com.itextpdf.xmp.impl.XMPMetaParser
> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |     71 | <clinit>  in     '' |    167 | parseFromBuffer in com.itextpdf.xmp.XMPMetaFactory |    153 | parseFromBuffer in     '' |
> 350 | close . . in com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp |    208 |
> close     in com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper
```

Searches brought me to Grails or Java as the cause.  I use JDK8 and the latest itext jar - 5.5.6. Grails has an old iText.jar - 2.0.8.  It's still com.lowagie.  Changing the imports and using the Grails supplied Bouncycastle and not a Grails service, but a true Java class, I at long last got it to work perfectly.

Here is the complete working code:

```
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Stamper {
    public Stamper(){
    }

    public byte[] stampDocument(byte[] orig) {
        try{
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(orig);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, baos);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(new URL("http://localhost:8080/IDSG/assets/stamp.jpg"));
            image.setAbsolutePosition(70f, 10f);
            image.scalePercent(40f);
            for(int i=1; i<= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
                PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);
                content.addImage(image);
            }

            pdfStamper.close();

            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```